# pandas concatenating dataframes and series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a master dataframe sdb which I wanna go through in a for loop, obtain unique values from certain of its columns and concat these into a new output dataframe df. the index is gonna be different for each series once it has unique values only. see below where I got to:

```
tbl = ''
i = 1
df = pd.DataFrame()

for col in sdb.columns:
    tbl = 'e_{}'.format(i)
    uni = sdb[col].nunique()
    if uni <= 25:
        tbl = pd.DataFrame(sdb[col].drop_duplicates())
        tbl.reset_index(drop=True)

    df = pd.concat([df, tbl], axis=1)
```

this code works until it gets to the last line and throws error: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame...
this is not clear to me as when i do .info() on both tbl and df they are shown as dataframes.
any thoughs much appreciated

Comment: `tbl` may be just a string, not a `Dataframe` object if `uni` is more than 25.

Comment: @yoonghm: thanks,I only want to capture situations where no of unique items in a column from sdb is <= 25 the idea is then to create a tbl dataframe (single column) with unique items. Not clear to me why pandas would see it as str within concat() method after its been made dataframe using pd.DataFrame()

Comment: If you have a column with number of unique value more than 25, then `tbl` will not of `DataFrame` type but a `string` type.  You can try to increase the value of 25 to a larger to verify.

If you really only want to `concat` when the unique number is less than 25, then indent the statement `df = pd.concat(...)` within `if uni <= 25:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate the situation:

```
import pandas as pd

tbl = ''
sdb = pd.DataFrame(
           {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
            'C': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
            'D': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]},
            index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

df  = pd.DataFrame()
print(sdb)
print('\n')

for col in sdb.columns:
  uni = sdb[col].nunique()
  if uni <= 3:
    tbl = pd.DataFrame(sdb[col].drop_duplicates())
    tbl.reset_index(drop=True)

    df = pd.concat([df, tbl], axis=1)

print(df)
```

The output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  2
3  4  4  3  2
4  5  4  3  2


   C    D
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
```

Comment: great, this works I believe it may have been the indentation in my original code..? anyway, many thanks for your help!